# Highlighting specific parts of the figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to know if I can use a particular type of formatting to differentiate one part of the figure from the text. For example, in the figure below, I would like to talk only about the role of part M5 in the system and would like to box it or bold it as I pause to explain one bullet of the slide. Subsequently, another part of the image would be boxed and so on.
                                 [image: figure]

Comment: It is hoped that the question is not a duplicate because the image is not created in Latex. So, I need to know how "remember picture" can help in this case.

Comment: You have an external image that you want to draw on. This is covered in [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/5764).